# Excel sheets Consoldate

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have a Excel workbook having morethan 10 Sheets and What i need is want to consoldate all sheets data in to single sheets, All sheets having same format data.Usually i use copy paste from each sheets without heading of each sheet but its taking lots of time. Is there any other way?please find attached sample [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kc2V.jpg]file for ref

Comment: Which version of Excel do you have?  Have you tried the Consolidate button on the Data ribbon?

Comment: Am using Excel 2016, Yess i can see consoldate option in Data Ribbon,If you dont mind can you help me how use this for above mentioned image working